# Reference type assigned to reference type

Tags: c#, reference

I want to ask if I get this example right, so if you assign reference type to reference type like:

```
ClassName p1 = new ClassName();
ClassName p2 = p1;
```

So If I would speak about first row, when you create reference variable (class), two things happened at one time. First the object of reference type (class) is created on the HEAP (on some address in memory) and second, the reference (address to place of created object) to this created object on the HEAP, is created on the stack and stored in variable.

For second row, I know, that from p1 reference will be copied to p2, so p2 and p1 will have same reference pointing to same object in memory (heap). But I really want to know what is happening behind it. I too know, reference that is stored in reference variable is allocated on stack.

So if I say what is really happening behind assigning Reference type to Reference type. Would it be: Because reference ("address" to object in memory) is in fact like "value type" (I don't mean object on the heap), so assigning reference type to reference type, I can understand like assigning Reference (address) by value?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Short answer is Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are many differences; a reference is similar in concept to an memory address; the variable just stores the address, so assigning the address to another variable just allows it to access the same memory instance.

Reference Type memory is stored on the heap, not the stack, but the address 'pointers' (variables) are stored on the stack. When they go out of all stack scope and thread storage scope, the heap memory is released.

There are lots of subtlties and differences between a managed memory system and the address/pointer concepts in C - but within the scope of your question it seems like you have the correct understanding.